# java.math.BigInteger pow(exponent) question

Tags: java, biginteger, exponent, pow

I did some tests on pow(exponent) method. Unfortunately, my math skills are not strong enough to handle the following problem.

I'm using this code:

```
BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(var);
```

Results:

- var | time in ms
- 2000000 | **11450**
- 2500000 | **12471**
- 3000000 | 22379
- 3500000 | 32147
- 4000000 | **46270**
- 4500000 | **31459**
- 5000000 | 49922

See? 2,500,000 exponent is calculated almost as fast as 2,000,000. 4,500,000 is calculated much faster then 4,000,000.

Why is that?

To give you some help, here's the original implementation of BigInteger.pow(exponent):

```
 public BigInteger pow(int exponent) {
    if (exponent < 0)
        throw new ArithmeticException("Negative exponent");
    if (signum==0)
        return (exponent==0 ? ONE : this);

    // Perform exponentiation using repeated squaring trick
        int newSign = (signum<0 && (exponent&1)==1 ? -1 : 1);
    int[] baseToPow2 = this.mag;
        int[] result = {1};

    while (exponent != 0) {
        if ((exponent & 1)==1) {
        result = multiplyToLen(result, result.length, 
                                       baseToPow2, baseToPow2.length, null);
        result = trustedStripLeadingZeroInts(result);
        }
        if ((exponent >>>= 1) != 0) {
                baseToPow2 = squareToLen(baseToPow2, baseToPow2.length, null);
        baseToPow2 = trustedStripLeadingZeroInts(baseToPow2);
        }
    }
    return new BigInteger(result, newSign);
    }
```

Comment: did you do a million runs of each of those calls and average the results to get the table you provided?

Comment: How many runs are you averaging the time from?

Comment: @vicatcu: I think it's safe to assume he didn't wait 3 years to get the results.

Comment: @Mark Byers :)

@mmyers & vicatcu: three runs. I did test a few months back on a different platform (windows XP vs windows 7, different HW, probably the same Java version) and the results were similar. I don't fully understand the alghoritm behind this power method so I would like to know what is going in the code. But you can see that 5,000,000 exponent is calculated in similar time as 4,000,000 exponent is. I would love to know why.

Comment: Beware the perils of the microbenchmark: http://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/JavaMicrobenchmarks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842695/what-is-microbenchmarking

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The algorithm uses repeated squaring (`squareToLen`) and multiplication (`multiplyToLen`). The time for these operations to run depends on the size of the numbers involved. The multiplications of the large numbers near the end of the calculation are much more expensive than those at the start.

The multiplication is only done when this condition is true: `((exponent & 1)==1)`. The number of square operations depends on the number of bits in the number (excluding leading zeros), but a multiplication is only required for the bits that are set to 1. It is easier to see the operations that are required by looking at the binary representation of the number:

```
2000000: 0000111101000010010000000
2500000: 0001001100010010110100000
3000000: 0001011011100011011000000
3500000: 0001101010110011111100000
4000000: 0001111010000100100000000
4500000: 0010001001010101000100000
5000000: 0010011000100101101000000
```

Note that 2.5M and 4.5M are lucky in that they have fewer high bits set than the numbers surrounding them. The next time this happens is at 8.5M:

```
8000000: 0011110100001001000000000
8500000: 0100000011011001100100000
9000000: 0100010010101010001000000
```

The sweet spots are exact powers of 2.

```
1048575: 0001111111111111111111111 // 16408 ms
1048576: 0010000000000000000000000 //  6209 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess:

the exponent is handled bit by bit, and if the least significant bit is 1 additional work is done.

If L is the number of bits in the exponent
and A the number of bits which are 1
and t1 the time to process the common part
and t2 the additional time processing when the LSbit is 1

then the run time would be

L*t1 + A*t2

or the time is dependent on the number of 1's in the binary representation.

now writing a little program to verify my theory...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how many times you've run your timings.  As some of the commenters have pointed out, you need to time operations many, many times to get good results (and they can still be wrong).

Assuming you have timed things well, remember that there are a lot of shortcuts that can be taken in math.  You don't have to do the operations 5*5*5*5*5*5 to calculate 5^6.

Here is one way to do it much more quickly.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring