# error opening HPROF file: IOException: Unknown HPROF Version

Tags: android, memory-leaks, dump

I am getting the following exception when trying to open HPROF file (created by `Debug.dumpHprofData`) with Memory Analyzer:

```
java.io.IOException: Unknown HPROF Version (JAVA PROFILE 1.0.3)
at org.eclipse.mat.hprof.AbstractParser.readVersion(AbstractParser.java:124)
at org.eclipse.mat.hprof.Pass1Parser.read(Pass1Parser.java:69)
at org.eclipse.mat.hprof.HprofIndexBuilder.fill(HprofIndexBuilder.java:65)
at org.eclipse.mat.parser.internal.SnapshotFactoryImpl.parse(SnapshotFactoryImpl.java:203)
at org.eclipse.mat.parser.internal.SnapshotFactoryImpl.openSnapshot(SnapshotFactoryImpl.java:114)
at org.eclipse.mat.snapshot.SnapshotFactory.openSnapshot(SnapshotFactory.java:143)
at org.eclipse.mat.snapshot.SnapshotFactory.openSnapshot(SnapshotFactory.java:123)
at org.eclipse.mat.ui.snapshot.ParseHeapDumpJob.run(ParseHeapDumpJob.java:56)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: under windows system you might find this post helpful 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168485/how-to-convert-a-heap-dump-in-android-to-eclipse-format

Answer (score 309, accepted):

The `hprof` file you get from Android has android specific format. You should convert `hprof` file take from Android OS into standard `hprof` format. For this you can use `hprof-conv` tool that is located at `AndroidSDK/tools/hprof-conv`.

For example:

```
hprof-conv android.hprof mat.hprof
```

And then open mat.hprof in Memory Analyzer.

EDIT: hprof-conv might be located under `AndroidSDK/platform-tools/` in some bundles.

Comment: @inazaruk hprof-conv used to run automatically when clicking the dump button, I'm not sure which version of ADT this stopped working but its likely a bug

Comment: @smith234, It might be true for the button in DDMS. But when `Debug.dumpHprofData()`  is used the conversion should be done manually.

Comment: I was getting a 'permission denied' error in the tools directory nevertheless.  I had to chmod permissions in that directory in order for it to work.

Comment: Typo: the latest version of MAT requires that the filename extension is hprof, not hpof as in the example above.

Comment: I get "ERROR: failed reading input" when trying to convert. Any idea? I use Android Debug Monitor 21.1.0 to produce the heap dump

Comment: just a heads up, my hprof-conv was under sdk\platform-tools instead in case anyone missed it under sdk/tools

Comment: I followed every step, on ubuntu but still am getting error "hprof-conv command not found" can anybody help http://stackoverflow.com/q/29489190/1994950

Answer (score 41):

If you are using Eclipse, just change the following:

1. Open Preferences (from the Window menu)
2. Navigate to Android->DDMS
3. Change the HPROF action to "Open in Eclipse"

Comment: In Windows 7 64bit, I couldn't convert using `hprof-conv` tool, it just didn't nothing. So tried your method and it works! I just should have to install MAT to eclipse and it now works perfectly. thanks

Comment: It might be good to update to explain that the user should open Eclipse preferences first and then select Android from the left hand menu etc

Comment: in Luna I needed to install MAT manually: Help-> Install New Software: http://download.eclipse.org/mat/1.4/update-site/

Comment: In my Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2) (Win 10) "Open in Eclipse" is already set and MAT is installed, yet I still get the "unknown HPROF version" error. I had to convert the file with "hprof-conv".

Answer (score 7):

`hprof-conv` tool location got changed.

It is now located at `AndroidSDK/platform-tools/hprof-conv`