# Memory management in Android 3.0 Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am developing an application for android 3.0 honeycomb and I wanted to understand the memory management in honeycomb. 
My application is actually a book & for each chapter we have these html-pages which we load in web view and these pages are not rendered from server but they are kept in assets folder. So at the end we have a lot of html files and images in assets folder.

Now the problem is that when we change the orientation of device the application crashes with `OutOfMemoryException`. Is this happening because of large size of the html or is it something else? Can this problem be solved if we had smaller sized html files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be because of the images. I was using images in one of my applications & i was experiencing the same issues "OutOfMemoryException", when i used the **System.gc()**, it worked for me. Please  see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000219/java-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget).

For [Android memory management please see this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk).