# How image resources are recycled?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-memory

Normally I always use `Drawable` resources in `Imageviews` because I haven't to manually release them.

But in some cases I need to dynamically create bitmaps and then I've to manually call `recycle()` on them in `onDestroy()`. That's the best solution I've found according to [that other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009086/recycle-imageviews-bitmap).

I want to understand how Android manages `Drawable` resources and why I haven't to manually recycle them. And when understood see if similar logic can be applied to manually created bitmaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Drawable` is much more broad than a `Bitmap`.  `Drawable` is intended to represent anything the graphics system can render to the display. There are subclasses of `Drawable` - such as as `ShapeDrawable`, or `ColorDrawable` - that do not contain `Bitmap`s and hence do not need any sort of manual memory management.

A `BitmapDrawable` wraps a `Bitmap` and contains a reference to a `Bitmap`.  The `Bitmap` is special, because Android maintains the pixel data for all `Bitmaps` in a separate heap, which is managed separately from the rest of your application.  When the Android garbage collector cleans up a `Bitmap` object, it also cleans up the the pixel data from the bitmap heap.  But you can force it to happen sooner by manually calling `recycle()` on the `Bitmap`, which marks the `Bitmap` invalid and releases its pixel data.

Android allocates a fixed size bitmap heap for each running application, and it is possible for your app to exhaust its heap by leaving too many `Bitmap`s in use at once.  That's why if your application uses bitmaps extensively, you will probably benefit from recycling bitmaps as soon as you know you won't need them.

**Update:** as noted in the comments, the separate bitmap heap applies to pre-Honeycomb versions of Android.  As of Honeycomb, the bitmap heap was merged with the application heap. Here's a [SO post with more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852943/what-does-bitmaprecycle-in-android-honeycomb-actually-do).

Comment: Then if I understood correctly there's any "magic". And if I manually create a Bitmap and set on Imageview after onCreateView I can expect that Android will release it in the same way it releases the ones created by image resources?

Comment: As long as your Activity isn't holding any references to the manually created Bitmap (for instance, in a static field or something), it will get cleaned up by the garbage collector along with all the rest of the View objects.  The recycle() method is useful   if you know you won't need the bitmap anymore, and want to free up the bitmap heap for something else.

Comment: This is although pre-honeycomb, since honeycomb the bitmap memory is in the same heap as the rest of the app.

Comment: @lxx - I was dimly aware of that change; thanks for the correction.