# Memory Analyzer (MAT) plugin not opening heap prof in MAT Eclipse 4.1.2 automatically

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-memory-analyzer

```
Eclipse SDK

Version: 4.1.2
Build id: M20120223-0900
Memory Analyzer 1.1.1.201108240735  Eclipse Memory Analyzer
```

Hi, I have updated my eclipse to latest version, also installed Eclipse MAT plugin but when I click "dump HPROF file" it doesn't opens in in MAT rather gives me option to save the HPROF file.

Previously it automatically opens it in eclipse MAT. Please tell me how to fix this ?

I have also switched to "Memory Analysis" perspective and tried to open HPROF file but it throws me following error

```
Error opening heap dump 'com.game.hprof'. Check the error log for further details.
Error opening heap dump 'com.game.hprof.hprof'. Check the error log for further details.
Unknown HPROF Version (JAVA PROFILE 1.0.3) (java.io.IOException)
Unknown HPROF Version (JAVA PROFILE 1.0.3)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this:

**in eclipse -> windows -> preference -> android --> ddms -> HPROF Action menu**

**choose: open in eclipse**

Comment: After trying your solution, I still get the same error.. I dont know what's going wrong?

Comment: try these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219049/error-openning-hprof-file and http://www.loni.ucla.edu/twiki/bin/view/MouseBIRN/EclipseSetup?skin=plain

Answer (score 13):

You can use **HPROF Converter** tool provided in android sdk.

The **hprof-conv** tool converts the HPROF file that is generated by the Android SDK tools to a standard format so you can view the file in a profiling tool of your choice.

```
hprof-conv <infile> <outfile>
```

More at [HPROF Converter](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hprof-conv.html)

After converting file opens without any Issue.

Comment: if you are using Android Studio/Android Device Monitor, this is the tool you need to use in order to open hprof file with Memory Analyzer. Thanks @Aduait

Answer (score 8):

In newer version of eclipse we need to set the default function for HPROF file and the default is "Save to disk".
Follow the following steps to fix this :)

Window -> Preferences -> Android -> (press arrow to expand Android View) DDMS -> HPROF Action -> select "Open in Eclipse"
see the image for reference

[image]