# Application closes without exception on Samsung GT-S7390

Tags: android, exception, samsung-mobile

I have developed an application for Android OS and there is occurred a strange problem. The app was tested on different phones (from version 2.3 to 4.4) and no problem. However, on Samsung GT-S7390 the app closes after many switching between fragments. Logcat doesn't show any error, and device didn't alert about crash. Very strange. I cannot understand is it up to my application or phone. Can anybody help me? Thanks. (Sorry for my English)

Comment: it maybe memory heap problem. check with MAT analyzing tool. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679995/memory-analyzer-mat-plugin-not-opening-heap-prof-in-mat-eclipse-4-1-2-automati

Comment: And also if you have used service class in your project, it would be stopped unexpectedly on low memory situation of the device. just check this also in your code.