# How to convert a heap dump in android to eclipse format

Tags: android, eclipse, heap-dump, mat

Im attempting to analyze a memory leak that has been driving me crazy for weeks, I found out about the eclipse `MAT` tool that helps you to figure out what is wrong, the problem is every single tutorial I have found says that I need to convert the format of the file from dalvik to  `HPROF` format, however not one single tutorial I can find explains how to actually do it, instead I get vague things like this

> Now the file you will get does not conform to the "standard" Sun .hprof format but is written in Dalvik's own format and you need to convert it:

`hprof-conv heap-dump-tm-pid.hprof 4mat.hprof`

what does that actually mean? what do I click? where do I go? Im totally lost and frustrated, any help will go a long way, thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use the [`hprof-conv`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hprof-conv.html) tool that's located in `[Android-SDK]\platform-tools`.

To do this on Windows:

1. Press <kbd>WINKEY</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type in `cmd`
2. Type in:

   `cd "C:\android-sdk\platform-tools"` (or whichever directory contains your Android sdk)
3. Assuming you have your Dalvik file on the Desktop (I'm just guessing the directory), type in:

   `hprof-conv "C:\Users\Edmund\Desktop\heap-dump-tm-pid.hprof" "C:\Users\Edmund\Desktop\4mat.hprof"`
4. This will generate the standard format HPROF file that you can use called `4mat.hprof`

Comment: I went there and clicked on it but it opens and immediately closes, not sure why it does that but Im unable to use it

Comment: You need to run it from the command line with those two parameters.

Comment: Ive never used the command line so far, is it the regular command line found in my windows machine or a special console in the sdk?

Comment: I may legitimately need a walk through of what to do in this process

Comment: It just keeps telling me "hprof-conv is not recognized as an internal or external command" when I type in the second part for some reason

Comment: You're not in the tools directory then. [Learn how to use the command prompt.](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos126/cmd-prompt.html)

Comment: Update, I went to the tools folder and looked at its properties, the directory I needed to go to was "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools" I did this and it worked however what Im struggling with now is step 3, is there supposed to be a space or hyphen in between the two file names in quotations?

Comment: now Im getting a "ERROR: failed reading input" this is way too hard, android needed to make an easier way to do this

Comment: Well, I tried my best to help. That error makes it look like there is something wrong with the input file according to [the source](https://github.com/android/platform_dalvik/blob/master/tools/hprof-conv/HprofConv.c). [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112671/android-memory-analysing-eclipse-memory-analyzer) has information on what people have tried to do, and you now know how to run the `hprof-conv` tool, so hopefully you can get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for your help appreciated it greatly!

Answer (score 3):

Just to be said: You don't explicitly need to convert the *.hprof* file using [`hprof-conv`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hprof-conv.html). *MAT* does this for you **automatically** - as [described here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html). In Eclipse,

1. open the *Preferences* Window,
2. navigate to *Android* > *DDMS*
3. and change the *HPROF action* to *"Open in Eclipse"*.

[image]

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work for Android hprof.. but it was worth a shot :)

Comment: cheers. I was ading the .hprof to the end of each file name on the cmd and it wasnt outputing the file.