# Hunting a memory leak with Eclipse and Mat, stuck converting the hprof file

Tags: android, eclipse, memory-leaks, terminal, hprof

This seems to be a question asked many times. I'm using Eclipse to write an Android app, in OS X. So far, no problem, except the app crashes sometimes, and I want to see whats going on so I can fix the problem. (Its probably related to bitmaps or variables not recycling correctly. But I don't know where else to start to look into it.)

I used the DDMS tool (in eclipse) to create a dump file. Then I downloaded the MemoryAnalyzer application to open it. Here is where I have been stuck for an hour: I have to convert the file first because Eclipse writes the hprof file in a different format. How do I convert it?

The answers to this question, [error openning HPROF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219049/error-openning-hprof-file), directly address my question. The top answer is the same as the reference for the hprof-conv tool.

> The hprof file you get from Android has android specific format. You should convert hprof >file take from Android OS into standard hprof format. For this you can use hprof-conv tool >that is located at AndrodiSDK/tools/hprof-conv.
>
> For example:
>
> > hprof-conv android.hprof mat.hprof
>
> And then open mat.hprof in Memory Analyzer.

I have a couple problems with this.

1. when I open the hprof-conv tool, it shows a handful of lines about it then says "[Process completed]".  And there is no place to enter any text. The only relevant info on the screen is this:

   > Usage: hprof-conf infile outfile
2. I'm in Terminal, so I open "new command..." or tried using the shell thats also open. Then when I run "hprof-conv dump1.hprof dump1a.hprof" I get the error "command not found". So I think I'm off track. I also tried "hprof-conf", instead of "hprof-conv", the way it suggests in point 1. Same error. Also tried various paths to the file, no change.
3. if I was on the right track, how do I correctly point this command to the file location? I have it on my desktop, and its named dump1.hprof. I'm not very experienced with Terminal.

Thanks in advance for an answer, or perhaps another suggestion on how to hunt down a memory leak.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to specify the full path to the command - `/full-path/hprof-conv dump1.hprof dump1a.hprof`

Answer (score 4):

If you are on mac add a ./ before the command :

```
./hprof-conv infile.hprof outfile.hprof
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello and sorry for a late response. I just went through exactly this problem and wrote some instructions here: http://spragucm.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/debugging-android-project-ddms-heap-dump-in-eclipse/

**Method 1: Use the Standalone MAT**

- go into c:...\sdk-tools\tools and copy hprof-conv.exe
- go to whatever folder you saved your dump1.hprof file and paste the .exe file
- open a terminal and change directory to the folder with your dump and .exe file (e.g. if folder is c:\Users\YourName\DumpFolder then type `cd c:\Users\YourName\DumpFolder`)
- When you're in the folder type the following in the command prompt and hit enter: `hprof-conf infile.hprof outfile.hprof`

NOTE: If you get an error about directory not found, you're not in the correct directory in the command prompt

- The outfile.hprof file should be in the same folder as the other files.

---

**Method 2: Using MAT in Eclipse**

- Install the plug-in for MAT in Eclipse
- Select to get heap dump as before
- Go to Window->Open Perspective->other->Memory Analysis
- Look through your tabs for a window with a blue disk icon in top left and expand the tab (this will have some crazy name on it with a very long string of numbers)
- Done...you are looking at the heap dump in Eclipse

Comment: Thank you!!!!  Method 2 is perfect. I don't know how i was supposed to figure that out. Call me a noob if you will, but I'm up and running now, figuring out how to use the tool, finally.

Comment: Can you help for my problem with ubuntu 14.04 http://stackoverflow.com/q/29489190/1994950

Comment: Sorry, but NO clue about Ubuntu...never even opened the OS