# Which "if" construct is faster - statement or ternary operator?

Tags: java, performance, if-statement, shorthand, premature-optimization

There are two types of `if` statements in java - classic: `if {} else {}` and shorthand: `exp ? value1 : value2`. Is one faster than the other or are they the same?

statement:

```
int x;
if (expression) {
  x = 1;
} else {
  x = 2;
}
```

ternary operator:

```
int x = (expression) ? 1 : 2;
```

Comment: I'm guessing there's absolutely no difference. It's just syntax. Unless compilers are somewhat evil (or something else) and I'm wrong

Comment: Did you (micro)benchmark it? Share the results.

Comment: Both will get jit'ed. There will be no difference at all. And don't bother decompiling the stuff. First thing that HotSpot does is to take out **all** optimizations that were applied by javac.

Comment: He's better off comparing the low-level bytecode.

Comment: The only thing you can say about the byte-code is whether it is the same.

Comment: I'd suggest `int x=1; if (!expression) x++;` - no, even better, *stop*  microoptimizations.

Comment: They don't exist for different speeds. They exist for different purposes. I'm sure you understand the difference between statements and expressions. Statements perform actions. Expressions produce values. `if` is for use in statements. `?` is for use in expressions.

Comment: @schnaader everyone knows ++x; is faster than x++ :P Besides, that code would actually be slower as it involves (when expression is false) 2 writes, a conditional jump and a read -- Compared to the original code where there was a condition jump, a write and a constant jump

Comment: +1 as the responses to this question are worth reading even if the intent of the original question is mis-guided.

Comment: @James: You're right. So, lesson learned: **stop** microoptimization :) It won't change anything or even make things worse.

Comment: @finnw - The downvotes are likely from developers who are weary of micro-optimization questions. Essentially they just amount to pontificating about things that have no real value in the real world.

Comment: If you are reading this, don't miss the [comment by James](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706696/which-if-construct-is-faster-statement-or-ternary-operator#comment27678765_4706785)

Comment: Regardless of which is faster, I would go for the `? :` because it is more readable and less verbose.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

There's only one type of "if" statement there. The other is a conditional expression. As to which will perform better: they could compile to the same bytecode, and I would expect them to behave identically - or so close that you definitely wouldn't want to choose one over the other in terms of performance.

Sometimes an `if` statement will be more readable, sometimes the conditional operator will be more readable. In particular, I would recommend using the conditional operator when the two operands are simple and side-effect-free, whereas if the main purpose of the two branches *is* their side-effects, I'd probably use an `if` statement.

Here's a sample program and bytecode:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            x = 1;
        } else {
            x = 2;
        }
    }

    public static void main2(String[] args) {
        int x = (args.length > 0) ? 1 : 2;
    }
}
```

Bytecode decompiled with `javap -c Test`:

```
public class Test extends java.lang.Object {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: arraylength
       2: ifle          10
       5: iconst_1
       6: istore_1
       7: goto          12
      10: iconst_2
      11: istore_1
      12: return

  public static void main2(java.lang.String[
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: arraylength
       2: ifle          9
       5: iconst_1
       6: goto          10
       9: iconst_2
      10: istore_1
      11: return
}
```

As you can see, there is a *slight* difference in bytecode here - whether the `istore_1` occurs within the brance or not (unlike my previous hugely-flawed attempt :) but I would be very surprised if the JITter ended up with different native code.

Comment: s/conditional statement/conditional expression/

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't mean for both `main` and `main2` to be exactly the same?

Comment: impressive. I didn't know you could compile byte code until just now.

Comment: @Kyle: I compiled the Java, then decompiled with javap.

Comment: Ohhh... You decompiled it to see what it compiled, to decide which style performed best?

Comment: @Kyle: Exactly. I'd mostly expected the bytecode to be *identical*. As it is, it's just *nearly identical* :)

Answer (score 10):

Both of your examples will probably compile to identical or nearly identical bytecode, so there should be no difference in performance.

Had there been a difference in execution speed, you should still use the most idiomatic version (which would be the second one for assigning a single variable based on a simple condition and two simple sub-expressions, and the first one for doing more complex operations or operations that do not fit on a single line).

Answer (score 8):

These are the same.  Both of them are fairly fast, typically around 10-30 nano-seconds. (depending on usage pattern)  Is this time frame important to you?

You should do what you believe is clearest.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to all the other answers:

The second expression is often called tertiary/ternary operator/statement. It can be very useful because it returns an expression. Sometimes it makes the code more clearer for typical short statements.

Comment: Great example of this in practice:
in Java, if I have to make a String final based on the result of an expression, i can use the ternary syntax 

    final String whichTable = (Integer.parseInt(clientId) > 500) ? "serverClients" : "offlineClients";

Then I can use the value of the expression in places where whichTable needs to be final.

The following would be illegal:
    final String whichTable = "";

    if (Integer.parseInt(clientId) > 500) {
        whichTable = "serverClients";
    } else {
        whichTable = "offlineClients";
    }

Comment: @JamesPerih In the case of a `final` field, you could use constructor blocks to set a value (although the conditional operator looks a billion times better IMO), and with local variables, you could assign a value before first use later in the code block you're in.

I think the only case where a ternary would give an advantage over `if-else` is when calling `super(...)` or `this(...)` inside a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

neither - they will be compiled to the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator is faster than if-else condition.

```
public class TerinaryTest {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int j = 2,i = 0;
        Date d1 = new Date();
        for(long l=1;l<100000000;l++)
            if(i==1) j=1;
                else j=0;
        Date d2 = new Date();
        for(long l=1;l<100000000;l++)
            j=i==1?1:0;
        Date d3 = new Date();
        System.out.println("Time for if-else: " + (d2.getTime()-d1.getTime()));
        System.out.println("Time for ternary: " + (d3.getTime()-d2.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Test Results:

Trail-1:

Time for if-else: 63

Time for ternary: 31

Trail-2:

Time for if-else: 78

Time for ternary: 47

Trail-3:

Time for if-else: 94

Time for ternary: 31

Trail-4:

Time for if-else: 78

Time for ternary: 47

Comment: I had exactly the opposite results when running your example, which shows that the results are unreliable. Unfortunately you are falling into microbenchmarking trap - it is notoriously difficult to do microbenchmarks correctly. For a couple examples you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842695/what-is-microbenchmarking

Comment: Your particular example suffers from a least these issues: 4 trials is nowhere enough, you run the tests in always the same order (first if-else, second ternary), you do not warm-up the JVM before running the tests, etc.