# Is it possible to shorten this if-else-if statement, and how do I do so?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have created this if-else-if statement and am wondering if I am able to shorten it so that it does not take as much space. If anyone knows how to do this, please help!

```
if (seatNum <= 20) System.out.println("Row 1");
else if (seatNum > 20 && seatNum <= 40) System.out.println("Row 2");
else if (seatNum > 40 && seatNum <= 60) System.out.println("Row 3");
else if (seatNum > 60 && seatNum <= 80) System.out.println("Row 4");
else if (seatNum > 80 && seatNum <= 100) System.out.println("Row 5");
else if (seatNum > 100 && seatNum <= 120) System.out.println("Row 6");
else if (seatNum > 120 && seatNum <= 140) System.out.println("Row 7");
else if (seatNum > 140 && seatNum <= 160) System.out.println("Row 8");
else if (seatNum > 160 && seatNum <= 180) System.out.println("Row 9");
else if (seatNum > 180 && seatNum <= 201) System.out.println("Row 10");
else if (seatNum > 201 && seatNum <= 216) System.out.println("Row 11");
else if (seatNum > 216 && seatNum <= 231) System.out.println("Row 12");
else if (seatNum > 231 && seatNum <= 246) System.out.println("Row 13");
else if (seatNum > 246 && seatNum <= 261) System.out.println("Row 14");
else if (seatNum > 261 && seatNum <= 276) System.out.println("Row 15");
else if (seatNum > 276 && seatNum <= 291) System.out.println("Row 16");
else if (seatNum > 291 && seatNum <= 306) System.out.println("Row 17");
else if (seatNum > 306 && seatNum <= 321) System.out.println("Row 18");
else if (seatNum > 321 && seatNum <= 336) System.out.println("Row 19");
else if (seatNum > 336 && seatNum <= 351) System.out.println("Row 20");
```

Edit: Included seat 201. Sorry for all the confusion!

Comment: `if (seatNum <= 200) {
    System.out.println("Row "+ (int)Math.ceil(seatNum/(float)20));
}
else if (seatNum <= 216) {
    System.out.println("Row "+ (int)Math.ceil((seatNum-45)/(float)16));
}
else if (seatNum > 216) {
    System.out.println("Row "+ (int)Math.ceil((seatNum-49)/(float)15));
}`

Comment: What about **201**. It doesn't fall into any condition!!!

Comment: Seat 201 might be for the fake audience member, if this is a Hypnosis show. Or it may just be unlucky in theatre terms. Don't jinx his code man!

Comment: I may have forgotten to include 201 in my code 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use the fact that `int`-divisions in Java will always round towards zero, meaning `5 / 2 == 2` and `-5 /2 == -2`.

For `seatNum <= 0`, the row is always `1`.
As long as `seatNum <= 200`, the row is `((seatNum - 1) / 20) + 1`. If it is `> 201`, we can simply take `((seatNum - 202) / 15) + 11`. We substract `202` because the numbers are set off by `2`: `216` is still in row `11`, `217` is in row `12`. Same holds for `231` and `232`. With this calculation, the undefined seat `201` will be places in row `11`, but ignoring this input or throwing an `Exception` instead is no big deal.

```
// if (seatNum != 201) { // optional, to neglect seat 201
    System.out.print("Row: "); // yes, I am that lazy...
    if (seatNum <= 0) {
        System.out.println(1);
    } else if ((seatNum <= 200) /* && (seatNum > 0) */) {
        System.out.println(((seatNum - 1)/ 20) + 1);
    } else /* if (seatNum > 200) */ {
        System.out.println(((seatNum - 202) / 15) + 11);   
    }
// }
```

If the rows get even more complicated / irregular, I would probably deploy a slight variation of [DAle's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44012656/4216641). This seems pretty readable and scalable.

Comment: The math is not quite right.  `setNum == 20` should yield `"Row 1"`, but yours yields `"Row: 2"`.  It also yields a different result than the OP's if `setNum` is negative.

Comment: Nit: this is equivalent only if seat numbers are all positive. That's likely, but should be noted. Also, integer division in Java does not always round down -- it always rounds towards zero, which is down for positive numerator and denominator.

Comment: There is probably a bug in OP's code because seat 201 seems to be missing, making things unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @JohnBollinger should be fixed now.

Comment: @MickMnemonic This only makes it more interesting ;)

Comment: @MickMnemonic turned out... I was thinking too complicated. Code should be (relatively) readable now.

Comment: Thanks, I did mess up on the 201 in the code, but this is perfect!

Answer (score 4):

```
int highestRowSeat[] = {20, 40, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 216, 231, 246, 261, 276, 306, 321, 336, 351};

for (int row = 1; row <= highestRowSeat.length; ++row) {
    if (seatNum <= highestRowSeat[row-1]) {
        System.out.println("Row " + row);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing one corner case (seat `201` is not defined in OPs code), but otherwise this looks like a clean and scalable solution.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can reduce is the number of checks, in this case, since you are using `if...else` the following conditions will be checked only if the previous one is false, so you can remove the *greater than* check from every `else if` because it will be auto checked by the previous one.

**EDIT** : Added additional check for the missing 201

```
if (seatNum <= 20) System.out.println("Row 1");
else if (seatNum <= 40) System.out.println("Row 2");
else if (seatNum <= 60) System.out.println("Row 3");
else if (seatNum <= 80) System.out.println("Row 4");
else if (seatNum <= 100) System.out.println("Row 5");
else if (seatNum <= 120) System.out.println("Row 6");
else if (seatNum <= 140) System.out.println("Row 7");
else if (seatNum <= 160) System.out.println("Row 8");
else if (seatNum <= 180) System.out.println("Row 9");
else if (seatNum <= 200) System.out.println("Row 10");
else if (seatNum <= 216 && seatNum != 201) System.out.println("Row 11");
else if (seatNum <= 231) System.out.println("Row 12");
else if (seatNum <= 246) System.out.println("Row 13");
else if (seatNum <= 261) System.out.println("Row 14");
else if (seatNum <= 276) System.out.println("Row 15");
else if (seatNum <= 291) System.out.println("Row 16");
else if (seatNum <= 306) System.out.println("Row 17");
else if (seatNum <= 321) System.out.println("Row 18");
else if (seatNum <= 336) System.out.println("Row 19");
else if (seatNum <= 351) System.out.println("Row 20");
```

Comment: Seat 201 doesn't exist in OP's code, so this isn't exactly equivalent.

Comment: This is technically shortening the code, but I meant the number of lines.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure

```
String s = "";
System.out.print("Row No. ");

if      (seatNum <=  20) s = "1";
else if (seatNum <=  40) s = "2";
else if (seatNum <=  60) s = "3";
else if (seatNum <=  80) s = "4";
else if (seatNum <= 100) s = "5";
else if (seatNum <= 120) s = "6";
else if (seatNum <= 140) s = "7";
else if (seatNum <= 160) s = "8";
else if (seatNum <= 180) s = "9";
else if (seatNum <= 200) s = "10";
else if (seatNum <= 216) s = "11";
else if (seatNum <= 231) s = "12";
else if (seatNum <= 246) s = "13";
else if (seatNum <= 261) s = "14";
else if (seatNum <= 276) s = "15";
else if (seatNum <= 291) s = "16";
else if (seatNum <= 306) s = "17";
else if (seatNum <= 321) s = "18";
else if (seatNum <= 336) s = "19";
else if (seatNum <= 351) s = "20";

System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

Two options worth exploring are using a `TreeMap` and binary search.

With a TreeMap, you could do something like this:

```
private static final TreeMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(20, 1);
map.put(40, 2);
//etc
```

Then in your method (add null checks as necessary):

```
int row = map.ceilingEntry(seatNum).getValue();
```

The binary search option would look like this:

```
private static final int[] rowEnds = { 20, 40, ... };
```

(that array needs to be sorted) and in your method:

```
int rowIndex = Arrays.binarySearch(rowEnds, seatNum);
if (rowIndex < 0) rowIndex = - rowIndex + 1;
int row = rowEnds[rowIndex];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to mention the [Conditional Operator ? :](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) . Although it does **NOT** give that much save of space, but it's good to keep it in mind as some programmers consider it more readable and a *little bit* [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706696/which-if-construct-is-faster-statement-or-ternary-operator) in executing.

```
String row = (seatNum <= 20)  ? "Row 1"  : (seatNum <= 40)  ? "Row 2"  :
             (seatNum <= 60)  ? "Row 3"  : (seatNum <= 80)  ? "Row 4"  :
             (seatNum <= 100) ? "Row 5"  : (seatNum <= 120) ? "Row 6"  :
             (seatNum <= 140) ? "Row 7"  : (seatNum <= 160) ? "Row 8"  :
             (seatNum <= 180) ? "Row 9"  : (seatNum <= 200) ? "Row 10" :
             (seatNum <= 216) ? "Row 11" : (seatNum <= 231) ? "Row 12" :
             (seatNum <= 246) ? "Row 13" : (seatNum <= 261) ? "Row 14" :
             (seatNum <= 276) ? "Row 15" : (seatNum <= 291) ? "Row 16" :
             (seatNum <= 306) ? "Row 17" : (seatNum <= 321) ? "Row 18" :
             (seatNum <= 336) ? "Row 19" : (seatNum <= 351) ? "Row 20" : null;

System.out.println(row); // to see the result
```

Comment: Note that its correct name is the [conditional operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

Comment: I've been told by a teacher to never use those. Would you agree?

Comment: @ap It depends on why your teacher doesn't recommend using them!  Conditional Operator ? : is very popular, however, your teacher's point might be for readability purposes, since beginners might get confused when they see them!

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a method for your code. Since the `return` keyword terminates the method, it can be used to shorten the if-else tree as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer>index=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String>excep=new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
        if(!seat(i).equals(seat(i-1))){
            excep.add(seat(i-1));
            index.add(i);
        }
    }

    for (int test = 0; test < 400; test++) {
        if(test<352){
            int i=0;
            for(;i<index.size();i++){
                if(index.get(i)-test>=0){
                    if(index.get(i)-test==0)
                        i++;
                    break;
                }   
            }
            System.out.println(excep.get(i));;  
        }else if(test==201){
            System.out.println(seat(test));
        }else
            System.out.println("null");
    }       

}

public static String seat(int seatNum) {
    if (seatNum <= 20)
        return ("Row 1");
    else if (seatNum <= 40)
        return ("Row 2");
    else if (seatNum <= 60)
        return ("Row 3");
    else if (seatNum <= 80)
        return ("Row 4");
    else if (seatNum <= 100)
        return ("Row 5");
    else if (seatNum <= 120)
        return ("Row 6");
    else if (seatNum <= 140)
        return ("Row 7");
    else if (seatNum <= 160)
        return ("Row 8");
    else if (seatNum <= 180)
        return ("Row 9");
    else if (seatNum <= 200)
        return ("Row 10");
    else if (seatNum <= 216)
        return ("Row 11");
    else if (seatNum <= 231)
        return ("Row 12");
    else if (seatNum <= 246)
        return ("Row 13");
    else if (seatNum <= 261)
        return ("Row 14");
    else if (seatNum <= 276)
        return ("Row 15");
    else if (seatNum <= 291)
        return ("Row 16");
    else if (seatNum <= 306)
        return ("Row 17");
    else if (seatNum <= 321)
        return ("Row 18");
    else if (seatNum <= 336)
        return ("Row 19");
    else if (seatNum <= 351)
        return ("Row 20");
    return "null";
}
```

Comment: That's kinda longer than what I had tho.

Answer (score 0):

What about this...

```
if(seatNum <= 0 ) 
    System.out.println("Row 1");
if(seatNum <= 200)
    System.out.print("Row "+ (int)Math.ceil(seatNum /20.00));
else
    System.out.print("Row "+ (int)Math.ceil((seatNum-201) /15.00 + 10));
```

Comment: every interval is not 20

Comment: Still buggy. with this calculation, seat `216` would be in row `12` instead of row `11`. Also, your output does not correspond with OPs code for number `< 0`. And there is the problem with seat `201`...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (seatNum <= 200) {
    System.out.println("Row "+ ceil(seatNum/20));
}
else if (seatNum <= 216) {
    System.out.println("Row "+ ceil((seatNum-45)/16));
}
else if (seatNum > 216) {
    System.out.println("Row "+ ceil((seatNum-49)/15));
}
```

I don't know the correct function names or anything about Java, but the logic of this works

Comment: `ceil` has no effect other than casting the `int` expression `seatNum/20` to `double` here. You'd need to make sure that floating point division is used, e.g. `Math.ceil(seatNum / 20.0)`.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that wasn't Java, I just put the general jist there :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write:

```
System.out.println("Row " + ((seatNum <= 200)?
                            ((Math.max(20, seatNum) - 1) / 20) + 1 
                          : ((seatNum - 202) / 15) + 11));
```

I ignored the `201` case which is probably an error (Change `202` to `201` if necessary).