# Testing the efficiency of Binary Search in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance, binary-search

I am trying to test the time efficiency of the binary search for large sorted arrays in java.

This is the binary search method I am using, which takes in the search key and the array.

```
public int binarySearch(int[] a, int k) {
    int l = 0;
    int r = a.length - 1;

    int m = 0;

    while (l <= r) {
        m = (l+r)/2;
        if (k == a[m]) {
            return m;
        }
        else if (k < a[m]) {
            r = m - 1;
        }
        else {
            l = m + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I think creating the array programmatically might cause an overhead in the efficiency. Therefore I am trying to initialize large arrays as constant and use it in the program.

I tried both Array and ArrayList as shown below.

```
public static int D10000[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, ..... 10000};

public static ArrayList<Integer> D10000 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...... 10000);
```

I am getting the following compilation error because the array size is too big.

```
Information:java: The system is out of resources. 
Information:java: Consult the following stack trace for details.
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type.map(Type.java:220)
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'SearchAlgo'
Information:javac 1.8.0_144 was used to compile java sources
Information:21/10/17, 12:02 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 1s 481ms 
Error:java: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

What is the best approach in achieving this?

Comment: If array size is too big to fit into the memory then you have to break the array into chunks of data and then search for that data in each chunk.

Comment: @javafan thank you. I understand to achieve the functionality. But I am trying to analyse the efficiency of the binary search method in terms of time. So I am looking to send a single array into the method and calculate the time efficiency.

Comment: Don't initialize it at compile time: initialize it at runtime.

Comment: Please be aware of this [What is microbenchmarking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842695/what-is-microbenchmarking) and that [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: @Zabuza thank you very much. That was useful. Seems like I will go ahead with the programmatically populating the array approach.