# Is Java instance of really so fast?

Tags: java, instanceof, jmh

I'm trying to measure if `instance of` really fast. Here is very simple benchmark:

```
public Object a = 2;

@Benchmark
@Warmup(iterations = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
public boolean test() {
    return a instanceof Double;
}
```

I ran this bench

```
Benchmark              Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
MyBenchmark.test       avgt    5  3.105 ± 0.086  ns/op
```

The assembly output of the benchmark is too long, omitted.

I also wrote a simple java program

```
private static Object i = 123;

public static boolean insOf(){
    return i instanceof Double;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        if(insOf())
            System.out.print("");
}
```

The assembly output of the compiled `insOf` method is this:

```
0x00007fd761114b60: mov     %eax,0xfffffffffffec000(%rsp)
  0x00007fd761114b67: push    %rbp
  0x00007fd761114b68: sub     $0x10,%rsp        ;*synchronization entry
                                                ; - com.get.intent.App::insOf@-1 (line 24)

  0x00007fd761114b6c: movabs  $0xd6f788e0,%r10  ;   {oop(a 'java/lang/Class' = 'com/get/intent/App')}
  0x00007fd761114b76: mov     0x68(%r10),%r11d  ;*getstatic i
                                                ; - com.get.intent.App::insOf@0 (line 24)

  0x00007fd761114b7a: mov     0x8(%r11),%r10d   ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007fd761114b9c
  0x00007fd761114b7e: cmp     $0x20002192,%r10d  ;   {metadata('java/lang/Double')}
  0x00007fd761114b85: jne     0x7fd761114b98          <-------- HERE!!!
  0x00007fd761114b87: mov     $0x1,%eax
  0x00007fd761114b8c: add     $0x10,%rsp
  0x00007fd761114b90: pop     %rbp
  0x00007fd761114b91: test    %eax,0x16774469(%rip)  ;   {poll_return}
  0x00007fd761114b97: retq
  0x00007fd761114b98: xor     %eax,%eax
  0x00007fd761114b9a: jmp     0x7fd761114b8c          <------- HERE!!!
  0x00007fd761114b9c: mov     $0xfffffff4,%esi
  0x00007fd761114ba1: nop
  0x00007fd761114ba3: callq   0x7fd7610051a0    ; OopMap{off=72}
                                                ;*instanceof
                                                ; - com.get.intent.App::insOf@3 (line 24)
                                                ;   {runtime_call}
  0x00007fd761114ba8: callq   0x7fd776591a20    ;*instanceof
                                                ; - com.get.intent.App::insOf@3 (line 24)
                                                ;   {runtime_call}
```

Tons of `hlt` instructions omitted.

From what I can see, instance of is about ten of assembly instructions with two jumps (`jne`, `jmp`). The jumps are a little bit confusing. Why do we need them?

***QUESTION:*** Is Java `instance of` really so fast?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking. Is it really _how_ fast? As fast as somebody claims? Fast enough to be used extensively? Or whether there is a faster alternative?

Comment: Please be aware of [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) and [What is microbenchmarking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842695/what-is-microbenchmarking).

Comment: @tobias_k The question is about number of instructions. As far as I can count, just 19 instructions (including jumps). But I'm not quite sure about how many jumps required. What it depends on.

Comment: @Zabuza Yes, I know, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is that fast for most cases, including the trivial case like yours. It first optimistically checks for the exact hit on the type (`Double` in your case), and then falls back to slow branch which would pessimistically call the runtime, because class hierarchy might need to be walked. But, in `Double` case, the compiler knows that no subclasses of `Double` exist in the system, and therefore slow branch is trivially "false".

```
   mov     0x8(%r11),%r10d    ; read the klass ptr
   cmp     $0x20002192,%r10d  ;   klass for 'java/lang/Double'
   jne     NOT_EQUAL          ; not equal? slow branch
   mov     $0x1,%eax          ; return value = "true"
RETURN:
   add     $0x10,%rsp         ; epilog
   pop     %rbp
   test    %eax,0x16774469(%rip) 
   retq
NOT_EQUAL:
   xor     %eax,%eax          ; return value = "false"
   jmp     RETURN
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. But I have one more question about it. You marked the line `mov 0x8(%r11),%r10d` as `read the klass ptr`. But in the original assembly output it was marked as `implicit exception: dispatches to 0x00007fd761114b9c`. Dispatches to the instruction followed after uncoditional jump which follows the `runtime_call`?

Comment: `%r11` is the object address. Klass ptr resides in its header at offset `0x8`. The implicit exception is the part of implicit null checking, which will SEGV if `%r11` is `NULL`, and the VM mechanics would dispatch that back to the normal code at the address you see in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're dabbling in disassembly, so you probably will have to reconstruct the functions represented by those jumps. Might be a good idea to use a JVM whose source code is available and for which you have the debugging symbols.

Just based on the semantics of `instanceof`, I'd wage that what these jumps do is execute the same test recursively for superclasses (since basically `instanceof` can be written in functional pseudocode as `instanceof(object, class) = class != null and (object.class == class or instanceof(object.class.superclass, class) or instanceof(any object.class.interface, class))`

Comment: Very very reasonble