# ND4J Execution Time

Tags: java, arrays, deeplearning4j, nd4j

Is ND4J faster than the normal Java arrays? I've done a basic test by initializing a 100x100 ND4J array then printing it, then did the same for a normal array. The execution time of the normal array is 10x faster. Any idea?

ND4J code:

```
INDArray a = Nd4j.ones(100,100);
System.out.println(a);
```

Execution time is around 1700 ms. For standard arrays it is around 150 ms.

Comment: Surprised this basic question got no answer from the ND4J community.

Comment: Because microbenchmarking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842695/what-is-microbenchmarking#2842707 Anything involving JNI will require set up time which takes longer than using plain old java. So it depends on how you plan on using them.

Comment: If you don't get an answer from us here, you could always try using our actual real support channels. Github issues or gitter are usually a better way of reaching us than stack overflow.