# Why is for...of loop so much slower than the traditional for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I setup a simple benchmark for comparing performance of `for (const x of arr)` and `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` loops. ([benchmark link](https://jsbench.me/k8l64oyy4s/1))

**Setup code**

```js
const arr = [...new Array(10000)].map(() => Math.random());
```

**`for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)`**

```js
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
}
```

**`for (const x of arr)`**

```js
let sum = 0;
for (const x of arr) {
    sum += x;
}
```

I have re-run the benchmark several times over, and each time, the `for-of` loop is almost 70% slower than the `for-length` loop. (~150k ops/sec vs ~43k ops/sec). This is very surprising to me.

What is the reason for this loop being significantly slower?

I have looked at the [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922066/why-is-for-of-loop-faster-than-standard-for-loop-for-small-arrays-and-slower-for) and the answers there dive into pros/cons of micro-benchmarking, and the conclusion was that switching the test order results in flipping the result. My case is different because I have large arrays (so no micro-bench issues) and I am using a test framework (jsbench.me) to avoid cold start issues.

Comment: I'm not big on Javascript, but wouldn't that be coming from the fact that the `for-of` loop uses Iterators (and all the overhead that comes with it) underneath whereas the `for-length` loop simply iterates over a memory section ?

Comment: You can optimize for...length loop even further if you save value of `arr.length` to a variable, because arr.length is an accessor (get/set method)

Comment: Just have a look at the specification for the _"why?"_ -> [`for`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-runtime-semantics-forloopevaluation), [`for...of`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-runtime-semantics-forinofloopevaluation)

Comment: @AzizHakberdiev That really shouldn't make any difference. Accessors have a time complexity of `O(1)` and even if it would make a difference, this would likely be optimized by the JIT compiler.

Comment: @Ivar bigO does not make any sense. Say, two functions have complexity O(1), but one of them calculates sum of two number, the other does division operation. First one will be way faster

Comment: @AzizHakberdiev True, but that doesn't mean that calling `.length` repeatedly is any slower. By all means modify the benchmark provided in the question to check if it makes a difference. (And make sure to run the test multiple times because differences this small can easily swap the outcome.)

Comment: @Ivar I have around 14-15% improvemnt

Comment: @AzizHakberdiev That's definitely not something I see. All outcomes are very close, twice using `array.length` in the array condition is slightly faster ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIbOM.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdSsv.png)), once using a separate variable is faster ([3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWN3P.png)).

Answer (score 2):

for...of accesses `@iterator` method (`obj[Symbol.iterator]` to access), which is a generator function that contains the for...length loop inside with `yield` statements

Comment: "_which is a generator function that contains the for...length loop inside with yield statements_" - Do you have any source for that? I'm pretty confident that the array iterator's code is native and depend on the JS engine that implements it.

Comment: @Ivar, https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/3.31.25/src/array-iterator.js?autodive=0%2F%2F even if array iterator is native, it still consumes resources to behave like generators