# Runtime of O(log(n)) function

Tags: c++, time-complexity, runtime

I made an AVL tree in C++, and the tree is kept balanced successfully according to all of my tests.
The function `addNode` should work in O(log(n)) (when n is the number of nodes in the tree), and it seems like my implementation satisfies it.
To verify, I wrote the following test:

```cpp
#include "AVLTree.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

typedef high_resolution_clock Clock;
typedef Clock::time_point ClockTime;

auto ExecutionTime(ClockTime start_time, ClockTime end_time)
{
    return duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end_time - start_time).count();
}

#define N 10000000
#define M 100000

int main(){
    AVLTree<unsigned long long, unsigned long long> tree; // AVLTree<key type, value type>
    ClockTime start_time;
    ClockTime end_time;

    std::vector<unsigned long long> vector;
    for (unsigned long long i=0; i<N; i++) vector.push_back(i);

    auto max_time = ExecutionTime(start_time, start_time); // currently zero, will get bigger.

    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    shuffle (vector.begin(), vector.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));

    unsigned long long counter = 0;
    for (auto i : vector){
        start_time = Clock::now();
        tree.addNode(i, i);
        end_time = Clock::now();
        max_time = max(max_time, ExecutionTime(start_time, end_time));
        counter++;
        if (counter == M){
            cout << "Small add: " << max_time << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "Add: " << max_time << end;
}
```

Because the function works in θ(log(n)), for sufficiently large n, T(addNode)<clog(n) (T is the time function) for some constant c, and if we take a really tight one, we may assume T(addNode)=clog(n) for large enough n. That means that the above test should output:

```
Small add: x
Add: (<2x)
```

For some x, and most time it does, but I also got

```
Small add: 280100
Add: 14432000
```

Which is almost 100 times bigger. Assuming the implementation is correct, why did it happen (it happens pretty rarely)?

Comment: One possibility is, the thread your program runs on is pre-empted by the OS and the CPU assigned to do some other task (e.g. flushing hard drive caches, or processing an unexpected burst of Wi-Fi packets, or whatever it is operating systems do in their spare time). [Microbenchmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842695/what-is-microbenchmarking) is hard. Rather than measuring each individual call, you may want to measure the average time over a large number of calls.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things going on in you code besides the actual `addNode` logic. These thigs are done 100 times more in the `M` case:

- Copying the next vector element to the `i` variable (use `const auto&`)
- Execution of `Clock::now()` which god know how many calls it does
- Calling the `ExecutionTime` function which uses an obscure amount of time to execute

Now consider if the running time of your `addNode` is in `O(log(n))` the effect of the above actions become more and more dominant as the size grows. To check this simply comment the `addNode` line and see the results.

Comment: But I did not measure the time of the whole loop execution, just the time of each ```addNode```. So the copy c'tor, the ```Clock::now()``` and the ```ExecutionTime``` affects are the same each time, and don't grow as ```n``` grows.

Comment: Alright this is true, can you share the actual code?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea because these are hundreds of lines, but Igor's answer seems to explain it. Thanks