# Size property vs Count() method in ArrayList - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In order to understand better which one out of the two is better, I wrote some code as follows

```
val nums = listOf(4, 5, 3, 2, 1, -1, 7, 6, -8, 9, -12)
val filterCount = measureNanoTime {
    nums.filter {e -> e > 0}.count()
}
val filterSize = measureNanoTime {
    nums.filter {e -> e >0}.size
}    
println("Time taken for filter size call: $filterSize")
println("Time taken for filter count call: $filterCount")
```

The output is as follows (and is consistent every time I run it

```
Time taken for filter size call: 4783
Time taken for filter count call: 65583
```

Here I have applied a simple filter to the array. It seems to contradict the discussion on this page - [Reddit Page Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/7k5vi3/kotlin_collections_difference_between_size_and/).
If anyone knows why count() seems to take more time, please share. Thank you.

Comment: Also, that Reddit post is saying saying that `nums.count { e -> e > 0 }` is more efficient and should be used instead of `nums.filter { e -> e > 0 }.size`.

Comment: What you are doing there is called microbenchmarking. You'll never get any proper results with tests that small. Here is a bit more info [What is microbenchmarking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842695/what-is-microbenchmarking).

Comment: @Slaw: Same result.

Comment: @Slaw: Yes, if the count is more effecient how come it takes 7 times the time. Also as per Reddit 

`@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T> Collection<T>.count(): Int {
    return size
}
`

This seems incorrect as per that logic. 
Sorry for pulling this. Just trying to understand the internals how they work.

Comment: It’s not just microbenchmarking that is skewing your results but also that you don’t allow warm-up time. It’s simply not a valid way to compare code performance.

Comment: The Short Answer is `count()` member has *operation* option, but `size` don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Alex.T in the comments, the problem is probably with your measurement method, rather than a discrepancy with the code you're measuring.

Here's a version where we run the algorithm 10 million times, which should hopefully account for any unrelated differences affected by what's going on in the JVM/System.

Result:

```
Average time taken for filter count call: 97
Average time taken for filter size call: 99
```

There doesn't seem to be much in it (which makes sense, since `count()` is inlined to `size` by the compiler, so they are executing the same code).

Code:

```
import kotlin.system.measureNanoTime

fun main() {
    val nums = listOf(4, 5, 3, 2, 1, -1, 7, 6, -8, 9, -12)
    val (filterCount, filterSize) = anshulBenchmark(nums)
    println("Average time taken for filter count call: $filterCount")
    println("Average time taken for filter size call: $filterSize")
}

fun anshulBenchmark(nums: List<Int>, iterations: Int = 10_000_000): Pair<Long, Long> {
    var filterCount = 0L
    var filterSize = 0L
    repeat(iterations) {
        filterCount += measureNanoTime { nums.filter { e -> e > 0 }.count() }
        filterSize += measureNanoTime { nums.filter { e -> e > 0 }.size }
    }
    return Pair(filterCount / iterations, filterSize / iterations)
}
```

Comment: BTW, I checked this with show bytecode -> decompile to Java in IntelliJ, and the `count()` call was indeed replaced with `size`, but it seems nothing got optimized away.

Comment: Correct. So the optimization on the memory side that was discussed in the Reddit thread is not true. Thanks, @Adam, this helps.

Comment: @Anshul, as Slaw pointed out in the comments to your question, the Reddit thread is comparing a different `count()` function to the one in your question.

Comment: @Anshul To confirm the above, I ran the two versions of the code through JMH and see no difference in average execution time. As noted, the `Collection.count()` extension function is inlined to `size`. But you're focusing on the wrong part of the Reddit post. Look at the comments to said post. They're talking about the `count` function which accepts a predicate. The reason why doing something like `nums.count { e -> e > 0 }` is more efficient than `nums.filter { e -> e > 0 }.size` (or `.count()`) is because the former _does not create an intermediate collection_, whereas the latter does.

Answer (score 1):

Your microbenchmark simply finds that whichever of the two approaches you run *first* is slower than the one you run second. If I run your code, I can reproduce `count()` coming out an order magnitude slower than `size`... but if I reverse the order of the tests and try testing `size` first, then suddenly `size` is an order of magnitude slower than `count()`. Such is the danger of this kind of naive microbenchmarking.

[As Adam Millerchip notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68488353/1709587), in cases where the compiler is smart enough to notice that an object you call `count()` on is a `Collection`, the call should get inlined to `size` and so (I think?) compile down to completely identical bytecode, thanks to this implementation of `Collection<T>.count()` in the Kotlin standard library:

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T> Collection<T>.count(): Int {
    return size
}
```

Certainly there's no way `count()` should ever come out *faster* than `size`, since `count()` just defers to `size` under the hood. At worst, the `Iterable<T>.count()` method will run, which checks if `this` is a `Collection` and defers to its `size` method if so (and thus must be slower since it's doing strictly more than a call to `size`). At best, the collection-specific implementation of `count()` will be inlined and you'll end up with identical bytecode as if you had written `size`. There's no way you end up *faster* than `size`, though.

Regardless, the quote from Kotlin in Action on Reddit was not claiming that the `count()` method is faster than the `size` method. Rather, it is saying that the `Iterable<T>.count(predicate: (T) -> Boolean)` method is more efficient (in execution time *and peak memory use*) than doing a `filter` call and checking `size` on the result, since the latter requires the construction of an additional `List` to hold the filtered results. That is, the optimal way to write the example in your question would have been *this*...

```
nums.count {e -> e > 0}
```

... and not *either* of the versions that you tried to benchmark.